# Exception - Invalid Argument replacement

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have been working on app scripts and have bben trying to replace text with an image url fetched from google drive, but when I execute the script it throws me an Exception: Invalid argument: replacement

The following are the code snippets of the related functions

```
    var image1;
var image2;
var imgid1;
var imgid2;
var latesturl;
var secondurl;
function clearcell () {
  var ss  = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var formS = ss.getSheetByName("Form"); // Form Sheet

  var rangesToclear  = ["B7","C7","D7","B12"];
  for (var i=0; i<rangesToclear.length; i++) {
    formS.getRange(rangesToclear[i]).clearContent();
  }
}

//-------------------------------------------------------------
//-------------------------------------------------------------
// Input Values

const pdfFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("13yA0y1MSaxTRYa2Os1Fpxl2FjBvvCdSE");
  const tempFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1ic-fcXJj5EHyaSEajhXe439OVLPKszm_");
  const tempDoc = DriveApp.getFileById("1QeM8yZLJbtsv_IDJVupXxrJX9kzD9tzCCcMvbyKTz7g");

  const newTempFile = tempDoc.makeCopy(tempFolder);

  const openDoc = DocumentApp.openById(newTempFile.getId());
  const body = openDoc.getBody();
  var email = Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail();
function submitdata () {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var formS = ss.getSheetByName("Form"); // Data entry Sheet
  var dataS = ss.getSheetByName("Data Sheet");

  var values = [[formS.getRange("B7").getDisplayValues(), 
  formS.getRange("C7").getDisplayValues(), 
  formS.getRange("D7").getDisplayValues(),
  formS.getRange("B12").getDisplayValues()]];
  dataS.getRange(dataS.getLastRow()+1,1,1,4).setValues(values);

  clearcell();

  body.replaceText("{TITLE}", values[0][0]);
  body.replaceText("{DRAWING_NO}",values[0][1]);
  body.replaceText("{REV}",values[0][2]);
  body.replaceText("{Change_Description}", values[0][3]);
  body.replaceText("{AUTHOR}",email);
  body.replaceText("{PREVIOUS}", secondurl);
  body.replaceText("{NEW}",latesturl);
 
  openDoc.saveAndClose();

  const blobPDF = newTempFile.getAs(MimeType.PDF);
  const pdfFile = pdfFolder.createFile(blobPDF).setName(values[0][0] + "_ECN_" + values[0][2]);
  tempFolder.removeFile(newTempFile);
  return pdfFile;
  
}

//------------------------------------------------------
// After Create ECN button press
function afterFormSubmit() {
  submitdata ();

  const info = e.namedValues;
  const pdfFile = createPDF(info);
  const entryRow = e.range.getRow(); 
  const ws = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Data Sheet");
  //ws.getRange(entryRow, 7).setValue(pdfFile.getUrl());
 // ws.getRange(entryRow, 8).setValue(pdfFile.getName());
  
 // sendEmail(e.namedValues['Email Address'][0],pdfFile);
}
function sendEmail (email,pdfFile){
  GmailApp.sendEmail (email, "The ECN", "Your ECN", { 
    attachments: [pdfFile],
    name: 'Dhruva Space'
    });
}

function createPDF(info) {

  const pdfFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("13yA0y1MSaxTRYa2Os1Fpxl2FjBvvCdSE");
  const tempFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1ic-fcXJj5EHyaSEajhXe439OVLPKszm_");
  const tempDoc = DriveApp.getFileById("1QeM8yZLJbtsv_IDJVupXxrJX9kzD9tzCCcMvbyKTz7g");

  const newTempFile = tempDoc.makeCopy(tempFolder);

  const openDoc = DocumentApp.openById(newTempFile.getId());
  const body = openDoc.getBody();
  
  body.replaceText("{TITLE}",info['Project'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{DRAWING_NO}",info['Department'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{REV}",info['Engineering'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{AUTHOR}",info['Revision'][0]);

  openDoc.saveAndClose();

  const blobPDF = newTempFile.getAs(MimeType.PDF);
  const pdfFile = pdfFolder.createFile(blobPDF).setName(info['Drawing'][0] + "_ECN_" + info['Revision'][0]);
  tempFolder.removeFile(newTempFile);
  return pdfFile;
  }

  function addFile(){
    var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("Index").evaluate();   
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(template,"File Upload");           
}

function uploadFilesToGoogleDrive(data,name,type){                          
  var datafile = Utilities.base64Decode(data)                               
  var blob2 = Utilities.newBlob(datafile, type, name);                      
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1hEDYhR_RcWAF3-BTQEnNiag5aenHkWIn"); 
  var newFile = folder.createFile(blob2);                                                                            
}

var folderId = "1hEDYhR_RcWAF3-BTQEnNiag5aenHkWIn";
function getLatestFile() {
  var files = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId).getFiles();
  var fileObj = [];
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    fileObj.push({url: file.getUrl(), date: file.getDateCreated()});
  }
  fileObj.sort(function(a, b) {return new Date(b.date) - new Date(a.date)});
  latesturl= fileObj[0].url;
  secondurl = fileObj[1].url;
  var ss  = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var formS = ss.getSheetByName("Form"); 
  imgid1 = secondurl.match(/[-\w]{25,}/);
  imgid2 = latesturl.match(/[-\w]{25,}/);
  image1 = DriveApp.getFileById(imgid1).getBlob();
  image2 = DriveApp.getFileById(imgid2).getBlob();
}
```

When submitdata function is executed, the error pops up

PS - I did try deactivating runtime V8, but it was throwing new errors rather than solving this one

Comment: Can I ask you about the relationship between `submitdat()` and `getLatestFile()`? Because in your function `submitdat()`, for example, the variables of `body`, `email`, `imgid1`, `imgid2`, and `openDoc` are not declared. Is this related to your current issue?

Comment: Those were globally declared, body is the current google sheet, email is the user's email using the google sheet, imgid1 and img2 contain the file id of the images which need to be replaced with the text. Latest file fetches the last image file id and submit data pushes the data and replaces the text placeholders with the data

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `Those were globally declared`, the variables of `body`, `email`, `imgid1`, `imgid2`, and `openDoc` are declaread as the global variables. Is my understanding correct? If my understanding is correct, the function `getLatestFile()` is run as the global. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Yes thats exactly correct, I have been trying to replace the text placeholder with an image using the following code https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/f84831455dea5c394e48caaee0058b26 which was uploaded by you, but that wasnt working as well, it was throwing the same error with invalid argument image, so I am trying to replace the text placeholder with the link to that image

Comment: Thank you for replying. First, I deeply apologize that my sample script was not useful for your situation. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this again. About your replying, I cannot understand your actual goal. Which do you want to replace the text with the image URL or the image blob?

Comment: I am trying to replace the the text placeholder with an image from google drive, whose url and file id have been stored in latesturl, secondurl and imgid1 and imgid2

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I understood that you wanted to replace a text with an image instead of the image URL. In that case, I think that [my sample script](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/f84831455dea5c394e48caaee0058b26) can be used. So can I ask you about the detail of `I have been trying to replace the text placeholder with an image using the following code which was uploaded by you, but that wasnt working as well, it was throwing the same error with invalid argument image`? By this, I would like to try to understand your current situation.

Comment: I tried using your script again yesterday, sorry I couldnt reply back to you yesterday, It throws me a exception - Invalid Argument - image when the replacetexttoimage function is called

Comment: Thank you for replying. It's no problem. From your replying `It throws me a exception - Invalid Argument - image when the replacetexttoimage function is called`, unfortunately, I cannot imagine your script and replicate your situation. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this. But I would like to try to replicate your situation. When I could correctly replicate your situation, I would like to try to think of a solution. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor skill.

Comment: No worries mate, Did you want a better look my code? If yes let me know how I can share it with you

Comment: Thank you for replying. I would like to support you. So, I would like to correctly understand your current situation, and would like to think of the modification. So in this case, can you provide your script for replicating your issue of `It throws me a exception - Invalid Argument - image when the replacetexttoimage function is called`? And also, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect as the image? By this, I would like to try to understand your question.

Comment: I have added the whole code I have written without the replacetexttoimage function included

Comment: Thank you for replying. From `I have added the whole code I have written without the replacetexttoimage function included`, unfortunately, I cannot still understand your issue of `It throws me a exception - Invalid Argument - image when the replacetexttoimage function is called`. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this. But I would like to try to replicate your situation. When I could correctly replicate your situation, I would like to try to think of a solution. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor skill.